# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: class lambda.Student cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable while using FlatMap

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Getting java.lang.ClassCastException when stream.filter returns multiple resullts

```
package lambda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LambdaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> stList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        stList.add(new Student("Ankit", 22));
        stList.add(new Student("Soham", 32));
        stList.add(new Student("Nitin", 42));
        stList.add(new Student("Xoxo", 55));
        stList.add(new Student("Chetan", 62));

        Department scrDept = new Department("Science");
        scrDept.getStList().add(new Student("Ankit", 22));
        scrDept.getStList().add(new Student("Soham", 52));

        Department artDept = new Department("Arts");
        artDept.getStList().add(new Student("Xoxo", 42));
        artDept.getStList().add(new Student("Chetan", 92));

        List<Department> deptList = new ArrayList<Department>();
        deptList.add(scrDept);
        deptList.add(artDept);

        deptList.stream().flatMap(dept -> dept.getStList().stream())
                .forEach(employee -> System.out.println(employee.getName()));

        List<Student> orderedPassedStd = deptList.stream().flatMap(dept -> dept.getStList().stream())
                .filter(student -> student.getName().length() >= 4).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Student std : orderedPassedStd) {
            System.out.println(std.getName() + "  ---------  " + std.getMarks());
        }
    }

}

class Department {
    String deptName;
    List<Student> stList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Department(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public Department(String deptName, List<Student> stList) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
        this.stList = stList;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public List<Student> getStList() {
        return stList;
    }

    public void setStList(List<Student> stList) {
        this.stList = stList;
    }

}

class Student {

    String name;
    float marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(float marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Student(String name, float marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

}
```

> Output : Ankit
> Soham
> Xoxo
> Chetan
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class lambda.Student cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (lambda.Student is in module javaMasterClass of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at java.base/java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare(Comparators.java:47)
> at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
> at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
> at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> at javaMasterClass/lambda.LambdaDemo.main(LambdaDemo.java:34)

Comment: if you want to sort your student objects, the student class must implement the interface compareable: https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the place, where you're trying to sort the students, based on your sorting need, you can provide a comparator in the following way:

Update the line which contains `.sorted()` to,

If you want to sort Students based on Name,

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName))
```

or

```
.sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName()))
```

If you want to sort Students based on Marks,

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getMarks))
```

or

```
.sorted((s1, s2) -> Float.compare(s1.getMarks(), s2.getMarks()))
```

If you want to descending sorting on Student's Marks,

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getMarks).reversed())
```

Answer (score 1):

sorted() method doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--

It says that when an element is not Comparable that ClassCastException exception will be thrown.

You need to either make Student implement Comparable interface and implement method compareTo like this

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    String name;
    float marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(float marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Student(String name, float marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        var cmp = Float.compare(this.marks, o.marks);

        if(cmp != 0) return cmp;
        //TODO add this.name == null logic depending on needs
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);

        //OR a one liner
        //return Comparator.comparing(Student::getMarks).thenComparing(Student::getName).compare(this, o);
    }
}
```

You can add any logic for comparing based on your needs. The convention is if this is > than o then compareTo returns integer > than 0, if they are equal 0 is returned, and if this is < than 0 , negative integer is returned. (
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
)

Or you can call sorted with comparator argument
`Comparator.comparing(Student::getMarks).thenComparing(Student::getName)`
(once again you can put some other logic in here)